# how to decompile an .exe file which is not a .net module

Tags: delphi, reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler

I am trying to decompile a file called App.exe. When I am trying to decompile this file using reflector it's getting an error that App.exe is not a .Net module.

Seeing this image you can get a idea that what I am trying to say:

[image]

Then I tried to check what language this file's written in using CFF Explorer. For App.exe it's showing this:

[image]

And for VSM.exe it's showing:

[image]

The two files are created by one company only but I cant understand why it is not decompiling.

Can't a .exe file which is not created in .NET be decompiled?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to decompile using the .net reflector..

Comment: ya i tried to decompile it using reflector but its of no use because its not created in .net i think.

Comment: .net and java use byte code, so reflector and it's equivalents can give decompile to high level language. So if it's native machine code, that's all you are going to get back. Is that going to be of use?

Comment: is there any decompiler for this App.exe,i know that we can decompile C#,VB app using reflector but for delphi is their any decompiler

Comment: I inlined your images, but you might want to use `Alt+Print Screen` next time to take a screenshot of just the app in focus instead of the entire screen. That would make them easier to see.

Comment: Yes, please crop those images!

Comment: You could try using DeDe (Delphi Decompiler) and Revendepro could help also. Do a search on Google for these, they are still around but not actively developed anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's article about decompiling Delphi applications: http://delphi.about.com/od/devutilities/a/decompiling.htm

It's a lot harder process than with .NET programs. What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @User: C++ is even harder to decompile than Delphi, for various reasons.  But for all intents and purposes, native code can't be decompiled with automated tools, and there are a lot of people who like it that way.

Comment: It can't be decompiled back to the original source code, but tools like IDA do understand enough about native code to reconstruct a good portion of the code, then you can fill in the missing gaps manually.

Answer (score 1):

Best results are obtained with [IDR](http://kpnc.org/idr32/en/index.htm) (Interactive Delphi Reconstructor) and [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) (the Interactive Disassembler) and [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/) (for forms/dfm)

Answer (score 0):

The application is not a .NET application, meaning it was compiled using a different compiler. So there will be no IL (Intermediate Language) elements for reflector to reflect on. This is exactly what you should expect.

You might start with Depends.exe

Comment: what is depend.exe can u please explain me.

Comment: Depends is just a dependency walker -- showing which DLLs are used by the EXE and which methods out of each DLL are used.  It doesn't decompile the executable code.  If the OP is trying to create source code for a Delphi app, they are going to have to use something a little more sophisticated.

Comment: is their any decompiler for this App.exe,I think this code is written in Borland Delphi 4.0 so i googled alot for this decompiler but did not found do u know any decompiler

Comment: decompiling Delphi is a few times covered on SO. Here is one :http://stackoverflow.com/a/335122/800214

Comment: Suggestion wrt Depends.exe has no value.

Topic starter shown his use of CFF Explorer, which also includes dependency walker, see his 2nd screenshot

Answer (score 0):

use protection_id.exe to determine the http://pid.gamecopyworld.com/

1. Compiler, and
2. Protector/Packer

Depending upon the compiler, there are various option, like

Ollydbg, DeDe, Interactive Delphi Reconstructor, IDA, etc

I would prefer DeDe for Delphi.

Comment: After I install the application how do I check the .exe?